# How to display Django model content into html template?

Tags: python, django

**I have a problem with displaying content from Model in Django. I was created example model with one field which is "title"**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

Then I am trying to create function in views.py which allow me to get objects from this field created in Django admin field, like this:

```py
def post_title(request):
    title = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'titles': title}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

And I am trying to display it in html file using template:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <p>{{ titles.title }}</p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 2</div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 2</div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 2</div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 3</div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 3</div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 3</div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">col 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to achieve displaying single string containt name of title in html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `all()` it returns a QuerySets which is a list. You need to iterate through it and display.

```
  {% for title in  titles %}
       <p> {{ title }} </p>
  {% endfor %}
```

So the above for loop is going to iterate through all your elements in the query.

Comment: I tried before what you provide, but it looks like it do not display anything even if I have one query creaty by django admin :/

Comment: Can you try using `{{ title.title }}` and double check if there is any data available in the database.

Comment: I found the solution, the way you said to return every element in the query is 100% good. But my problem occur becuase of multiple application in Django with different html files. I wasn't sure if I could display same "view.py" in different application, but finally I found the way to do it - changing skeleton of application as well I removed redundant files